# Understanding of undocumented conversion from lon., lat. coordinates of Earth surface to x, y coordinates of image

Tags: javascript, coordinates, gis, coordinate-systems

I try to implement few features on a weather radar image received from weather provider. On the providers web I found a function which converts coordinates from a user input to pixel coordinates in the image.
Because all variables are anonymized and the code is undocumented I can't figure out how the function works. I know very little about coordinate reference systems and the CRS of the image of map is unknown therefore I need advice.

In the code below you can see my progress of the code analyzation. I spend nearly a day trying to figure out what variable un25 represent. Unsuccessfully. I can't blindly paste the whole function in my project I need to understand the theory behind.

```
function lonlat2xy(lonUsrD, latUsrD) { //user input position in lon a lat in degrees
    var oneRadOfDegree = 57.29577951308232; //  for conversion of degrees to rads
    var latPragR = 50.008 / oneRadOfDegree; //lat. of base station, default position in rads
    var lonPragR = 14.447 / oneRadOfDegree; //lon. of base station, default position in rads
    var leftPragPx = 301.5;                 // length from left side of image to base station in px
    var topPragPx = 217.5;                  // length from top side of image to base station in px
    var ratioMap = 1.0;                     //ratio of the map (always 1 for thos example)
    var radiusEarth = 6378.144;         //radius of Earth
    var pi1 = 3.141592653589793;    //pi
    var pi2 = 6.283185307179586;    //2pi
    var pi05 = 1.570796326794897;   //0.5pi
    var lonUsrRNeg = -1 * (lonUsrD / oneRadOfDegree); //inversed user lon. position in rads
    var latUsrR = latUsrD / oneRadOfDegree;              //user lat. position in rads
    var lonPragRNeg = -1 * lonPragR;                     //inversed base station lon. position in rads
    var latPragR1 = latPragR;                            //base station lat. position in rads

    //?????? No idea what this formula does
    var un25 = (Math[sin](latUsrR) * Math[sin](latPragR1)) + (Math[cos](latUsrR) * Math[cos](latPragR1) * Math[cos](lonUsrRNeg - lonPragRNeg));
    sin()
    //??????

    var un26 = Math[acos](un25);

    un25 = Math[sin](latUsrR) - (Math[sin](latPragR1) * un25);
    var un27 = (Math[cos](latPragR1) * Math[sin](un26));


    if (un27 != 0) {
        un25 = un25 / un27;
    } else {
        un25 = 0;
    }

    var un28 = Math[acos](un25); 
    var lonDiffPragUsr = lonUsrRNeg - lonPragRNeg;
    if ((lonUsrRNeg > lonPragRNeg) && (lonDiffPragUsr < pi1)) {
        un28 = pi2 - un28; 
    }

    var un2a = un26;
    var un2b = un28; 
    var xPxImg, yPxImg, un2e;
    if (un2a < pi05) {
        un2e = Math[tan](un2a);
        xPxImg = un2e * Math[sin](un2b); 
        yPxImg = un2e * Math[cos](un2b);
    } else {
        xPxImg = 0;
        yPxImg = 0;
    }
    //[xy]PxImg - wrong name - I dont know what exactly this var represent
    xPxImg = leftPragPx + (xPxImg * radiusEarth) / ratioMap; //IMG-x = (IMGx prazske stanice)  + ((2PI*(pixN/pix360)) * polomer zeme)/ 1 ... ratio
    yPxImg = topPragPx - ((yPxImg * radiusEarth) / ratioMap);


    //Clear part from here
    var xPxImgRo = Math[round](xPxImg); //Round IMG-x
    var yPxImgRo = Math[round](yPxImg); //Round IMG-y

    out_xy = new Array(2);  //create array for rturn
    out_xy[0] = xPxImgRo;
    out_xy[1] = yPxImgRo;

    return out_xy; 
}
```

URLS

providers app: http://portal.chmi.cz/files/portal/docs/meteo/rad/data_jsradview.html

example of the picture for the coordinate conversion: http://portal.chmi.cz/files/portal/docs/meteo/rad/data_tr_png_1km/pacz23.z_max3d.20190824.1100.0.png

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this document https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/44390425.pdf
As far as I got this is all about spheroidal gnomonic projection. You can try to go in that direction to find more of a theoretical background.

Few more links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GnomonicProjection.html
- https://www.imo.net/observations/methods/visual-observation/minor/gnomonic/